# I have 2 SSD's (windows and ubuntu), but the SSD with Ubuntu not being recognized alone, only when together with Windows's SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, ssd

First let me me explain the context. I have a laptop (I'll call it computer A) with 2 hard-drives, a 480GB SSD with Windows and a 120GB SSD with Ubuntu. My boot priority in bios is setup to Ubuntu first. /i have GNU GRUB boot menu installed in Ubuntu, so in the beggining I can choose between the OS's: Ubuntu or Windows. Ok so far, the issues come next.

I bought a new computer (will call it computer B) with preinstalled Windows and wanted to use the 120GB SSD with Ubuntu (from computer A) on it as primary hard-drive to boot. I installed the SSD wiht Ubuntu on computer B, but Ubuntu wasn't being started. Actually, inside BIOS menu of computer B, I could see that the SSD with Ubuntu was there, but when I tried to boot it, is like if it is ignored and so the Windows (preinstalled) is booted.

So I did a test: in computer A, I removed the SSD with Windows and let only the SSD with Ubuntu. But when turn on the computer, the Ubuntu doesn't starts and it goes directly to BIOS menu. In the BIOS menu, I saw that the SSD with Ubuntu wasn't there, like if there was no SSD's on it. So I put back the SSD with Windows, went to BIOS menu, and could see both SSDs there, and I even could start Ubuntu normally. Also if I let only the SSD with Windows, Windows starts normally. But the same doesn't happens to SSD with Ubuntu.

I don't know why, but it feels like the SSD with Ubuntu depends on the SSD with Windows to be booted. I tried to remove the GRUB boot menu from Ubuntu, but I still couldn't boot the SSD with Ubuntu alone, without the other SSD with Windows. And I need to make it work so I can move Ubuntu's SSD from computer A to computer B.

Please help! If the situation wasn't clear, I'll be here to answer questions. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add UEFI boot entries with efibootmgr or full reinstall boot loaders. On Windows machine it may be just reorder default boot entry either with efibootmgr -o or from within UEFI settings. see `man efibootmgr` You also may have Ubuntu in Windows drive's ESP, so need an ESP on Ubuntu drive. Only one computer here & ask another question if still issues on other. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer  or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred sorry i'm a layman in this subject, did not really understand what you said. Can we talk somewhere else please? here is my facebook https://www.facebook.com/JoaovitoorMelo/

Comment: This is a question & answer site. Answers need to be posted so others can find then if issue is resolved. You just need to use Ubuntu live installer in live mode, and follow instructions in link to use ppa to add Boot-Repair. It will offer to fix (do not do, unless after review someone says that is best option) and upload a report to pastebin site. copy & paste the link & post link in your question above.

Comment: [SOLVED] Worked!! I followed the steps of the link you sent, Boot-Repair. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @oldfred I solved my issue. Just followed the steps in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Thanks a lot!